# error in MapReduce ( hadoop ) Program - citationHistogram

Tags: hadoop

```
package lab.dummy;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.lang.*;

public class PatCitedCount extends Configured implements Tool
{
public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable>
{ 

    private final static IntWritable uno = new IntWritable(1);

    private IntWritable citationCount= new IntWritable();

    public void map(Text key, Text value,

    OutputCollector<IntWritable, IntWritable> output, 
    Reporter reporter ) throws IOException
    {

    citationCount.set(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));

    output.collect(citationCount,uno);  
    }
 }
 public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase 

implements Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable>
{ 
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
OutputCollector<IntWritable, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter )
throws IOException
    {

    int count= 0;

    while(values.hasNext())
        {
        count+=values.next().get();
        }
    output.collect(key, new IntWritable(count));
        }
}
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

    Configuration conf = getConf();

    JobConf job = new JobConf( conf, PatCitedCount.class );

    job.setJarByClass(getClass());

    Path in = new Path( args[0] );

    Path out = new Path( args[1] );

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths( job, in );

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath( job, out );

    job.setJobName( "PatCitedCount" );

    job.setMapperClass( MapClass.class );

    job.setReducerClass( Reduce.class );

    job.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);

    job.setOutputFormat( TextOutputFormat.class );

    job.setOutputKeyClass( IntWritable.class );

    job.setOutputValueClass( IntWritable.class );

    JobClient.runJob(job);

    return 0;

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

int res= ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new PatCitedCount(), args);

System.exit(res);
}
}
```

I am getting following errors :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
-at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
-at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
-at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
-at lab.dummy.PatCitedCount$MapClass.map(PatCitedCount.java:60)
-at lab.dummy.PatCitedCount$MapClass.map(PatCitedCount.java:1)
-at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
-at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
-at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
-at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
-at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
-at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
-at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
-at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

Comment: check your input file, value is coming as "" and you are trying to convert empty string to integer.

Comment: thanks ...I have checked input txt file thoroughly and found that few values are inside double quote " ". I have deleted those and program successfully completed.

Comment: I have added the answer as below so that it would help others in future with people facing the same issue. Please check it and see if that helped you and close this question by accepting the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Use the last job's(citation_count) result as input instead of the file "cite75_99.txt". Everything will be fine.  :D

Answer (score 1):

You have some empty values in the file which your mapper is reading from hdfs. You are trying to convert that empty value to number which is invalid and hence you are getting NumberFormatException.

You will need to check and get rid of those lines or in your mapper you would need to manually check for something like:

```
try {
    citationCount.set(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
    output.collect(citationCount,uno);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    //handle exception if you want.
}
```